# Python: Create an infinite list that takes user input in

Tags: python

Hey I'm trying to create an infinite list in python that takes user input in till 0 is entered, I don't really know if this is the right way to do so, here's what I did:

```
    `n = input("Enter a list element separated by space ")
        while n == 0:
            break
        else:
            list = n.split() 
     print(list)`
```

Thank you!

Comment: The code you have posted is not a valid python code. Please submit a valid code and explain what is the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Please update your question with your real code. There are several mistakes in your post which will stop it from running.

Comment: It will show NameError: name 'n' is not defined, coz instead of specifying a range for n say (1:5), i want it to print an infinite list but idk what number to put in for n

Comment: Please update your question with ‘n=5’ as an example.

Comment: I just update my code!

Comment: hey wups, sorry dont really know how to reply to your message specifically, I'm lookin for similar things but more of how to convert user input into a list

Comment: Now you have completely changed your code. It looks nothing like your description of what you want to do.

Comment: hey quamrana, just had a new idea all sudden so i changed it completely, all i want it's just keep take user input as a list and, when user enter 0 the list will stop

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you originally described:

```py
Numbers = []

while True:
    number = int(input("Please enter a number:"))
    if number == 0:
        break
    Numbers.append(number)

print(Numbers)
```

Comment: yassss this is what im lookin for! thank you so much, but could you pls explain to me that why isn't my code running properly?

Comment: Lots of the comments have already tried to explain why your code isn’t running. Without seeing your *actual* code I can do no better.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
l = []
while 1:
   n = input("Enter a list element seperated by a space")
   for x in n.split():
       if x == 0:
           break
       l.append(int(x))
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help, but the code did not stop when 0 is entered and the number 0 was shown in the list

Comment: see the edited file

Comment: This is what i got running the code:                                                                                                 "Enter a list element separated by a space: 3 4 5 0
['3', '4', '5', '0']
[3, 4, 5, 0] "                                                                                                            same outcome as my code :D, im trying to get rid of the 0 in the list, so when 0 is entered, it wont be printed in the list

Comment: you said infinite loop right

Comment: Yes before appending you should break... Apart from that this would take inputs for ever...

Comment: hey Ekure, its will just keep take user input to a list till 0 is entered, then the list should stop taking input, print the list but without number 0

Comment: edit your question